# Installing glib-2.50.1: No package 'libpcre' founbd

Tags: software-installation, pkg-config

[UPDATE]

As per fkraiem's suggestion below, about the rabbithole (indeed, it does feel like that!), this is the **first problem** I encounter, and the reason I'm trying to install glib *et al.*

After running ./configure with pspp-0.10.2:

> configure: error: The following required prerequisites are not
>   installed. You must install them before PSPP can be built:
>
> cairo 1.5 or later and pango 1.22 or later (or use --without-cairo)
>
> gthread 2.0 (or use --without-gui)
>
> gtk+ 3.0 version 3.4.2 or later (or use --without-gui)
>
> gtksourceview 3.0 version 3.4.2 or later (or use --without-gui)
>      glib 2.0 version 2.32 or later (or use --without-gui)

Though the Synaptic Package Manager shows I have Cairo 1.14.6-1 installed,

[ORIGINAL POST]

When trying to install glib-2.50.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 I receive the following error -

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libpcre >= 8.13) were not met:
No package 'libpcre' found
```

*None* of the existing posts about this issue provide any solutions.

I have pkg-config installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep pkg-config

ii  libextutils-pkgconfig-perl 1.15-1        all          Perl
```

interface to the pkg-config utility
    ii  pkg-config 0.29.1-0ubuntu1  amd64        manage compile and link
flags for libraries

And have a pckconfig folder in both `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib/local`. Both folders contain:

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/blas.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/blas-netlib.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/dbus-python.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gsl.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/harfbuzz.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/harfbuzz-icu.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ibus-table.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/lapack.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/lapack-netlib.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcryptsetup.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libffi.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgdiplus.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libquvi-scripts.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libR.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/notify-python.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/pango.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/pangocairo.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/pangoft2.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/pm-utils.pc
```

Regarding the PKG_CONFIG_PATH

```
$ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
```

yields

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib
/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

And

```
ldconfig -v | grep pcre
```

yields

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or
directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file
or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than
once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic
linker, ignoring
        libpcre.so.3 -> libpcre.so.3.13.2       libpcreposix.so.3 ->
libpcreposix.so.3.13.2  libpcre32.so.3 -> libpcre32.so.3.13.2
        libpcre++.so.0 -> libpcre++.so.0.0.0    libpcre16.so.3 ->
libpcre16.so.3.13.2     libpcrecpp.so.0 -> libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic
linker, ignoring
```

I'm here because I'm trying to install PSPP v0.10.2 of PSPP. The installation guide cautions that:

```
* pkg-config (http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/).  Versions
  0.18 and 0.19 have a bug that will prevent library detection,
  but other versions should be fine.
```

But since I'm using 0.29 I assume that bug isn't relevant?

Comment: You are trying to install PSPP; are you sure it needs glib 2.50? Have you tried the glib from the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: Good point. But that's where I don't understand why it's falling apart. It requires GTK+ which won't install: checking for BASE_DEPENDENCIES... no
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.49.4    atk >= 2.15.1    pango >= 1.37.3    cairo >= 1.14.0    cairo-gobject >= 1.14.0    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.30.0) were not met:

No package 'glib-2.0' found
No package 'atk' found
Package 'glib-2.0', required by 'pango', not found

Comment: Most likely, you just need to install the GTK+ development files from the repositories (package `libgtk3-dev`).

Comment: I have libgtk3-dev (version 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1) but still no success

Comment: It is very unclear what your actual problem is, so please edit your question to describe **the first problem** you encounter when trying to install PSPP. As it is, it seems you are trying to apply the wrong solution to it.

Comment: I'm running 16.04 here with `libpcre3-dev`, and `pkg-config --modversion libpcre` returns `8.38` - I don't understand why you are diving down a rabbithole of locally installed libraries and pkg-config paths

Comment: @steeldriver. pkg-config --modversion libpcre returns: 

Package libpcre was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libpcre.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libpcre' found.

Comment: OK so have you installed the appropriate **development** packages? These are different from (additional to) the **runtime** library packages i.e. when you say *"Synaptic Package Manager shows I have Cairo 1.14.6-1"* does that mean `libcairo2` or `libcairo2-dev` 1.14.6-1?

Comment: @steeldriver. Thanks for the comment. Yes, both are installed.

Comment: So... `dpkg` seems to indicate that you don't have the pkg-config *package* installed - yet you are able to run the pkg-config command; when you do, it doesn't appear to be searching the default paths: does this indicate that you installed pkg-config from elsewhere (perhaps from source)?

Comment: @steeldriver. I think so, and I suppose that's the problem. When I updated the repositories to use *yakkety main universe* I was able to install pspp__0.10.1-2 via synaptic. But what did I do wrong to not be able to extract the pspp tar and install via ./configure ?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you actually using? I'm afraid it sounds like you have made a terrible mess by installing a bunch of unnecessary stuff in unnecessary ways. It's going to be hard to unscramble - especially if you can't remember what you did, exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47058/discussion-between-lithic-and-steeldriver).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering this question later in time. I've ran into similar problems compiling pspp on ubuntu 16.04. The packages I installed (sudo apt install) to solve the issue were as follows:

```
sudo apt install libxml2-dev
libcairo2-dev
libreadline-dev
libglib2.0-dev
libgsl-dev
libgtk-3-dev
libgtksourceview-3.0-dev
```